# How to sort array of objects by object value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've a problem with sorting in js.
My array of objects looks like this one:

```
var listArr = [
  { 'year': 2011, 'movie': 'Some movie' },
  { 'year': 1990, 'movie': 'Some movie' },
  { 'year': 2017, 'movie': 'Some movie' },
  { 'year': 2005, 'movie': 'Some movie' },
  { 'year': 1999, 'movie': 'Some movie' },
  { 'year': 2015, 'movie': 'Some movie' }
];
```

How to sort this array by year?
I want to get out this:

```
var listArr = [
  { 'year': 2017, 'movie': 'Some movie' },
  { 'year': 2015, 'movie': 'Some movie' },
  { 'year': 2011, 'movie': 'Some movie' },
  { 'year': 2005, 'movie': 'Some movie' },
  { 'year': 1999, 'movie': 'Some movie' },
  { 'year': 1990, 'movie': 'Some movie' }
];
```

Comment: Use the handy [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method? You can pass in your own comparison function.

Comment: I don't know how?

Comment: Really? I just linked an article explaining how it works... and @nina-scholz has given you another question to look at for an answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
listArr.sort(function (x, y) {
  return y.year - x.year;
});
```

Comment: The question has already been marked as a duplicate. Please don't post answers to such questions.

Comment: @evolutionxbox this question as marked as duplicate while i'm posting the answer.

Comment: Yeah I get it. Although, it was marked as duplicate 5 mins before you posted. Next time check if a question has a duplicate before answering.